# Why does boost::bind store arguments of the type passed in rather than of the type expected by the function?

Tags: c++, boost, boost-bind

I recently ran into a bug in my code when using [boost::bind](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_50_0/libs/bind/bind.html).

From the boost::bind docs:

> The arguments that bind takes are copied and held internally by the returned function object.

I had assumed that the type of the copy that was being held was based on the signature of the function.  However, it is actually based on the type of the value passed in.

In my case an implicit conversion was happening to convert the type used in the bind expression to the type received by the function.  I was expecting this conversion to happen at the site of the bind, however it happens when the resulting function object is used.

In retrospect I should have been able to figure this out from the fact that using boost::bind gives errors when types are not compatible [only at the call site, not the bind site](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_50_0/libs/bind/bind.html#err_signature).

My question is:
Why does boost::bind work this way?

1. It seems to give worse compiler error messages
2. It seems to be less efficient when implicit conversion happens and there are multiple calls to the functor

But given how well Boost is designed I'm guessing there is a reason.  Was it behavior inherited from std::bind1st/bind2nd?  Is there a subtle reason why this would be hard/impossible to implement?  Something else entirely?

To test that second theory I wrote up a little code snippet that seems to work, but there may well be features of bind I haven't accounted for since it's just a fragment:

```
namespace b = boost;
template<class R, class B1, class A1>
   b::_bi::bind_t<R, R (*) (B1), typename b::_bi::list_av_1<B1>::type>
   mybind(R (*f) (B1), A1 a1)
{
   typedef R (*F) (B1);
   typedef typename b::_bi::list_av_1<B1>::type list_type;
   return b::_bi::bind_t<R, F, list_type> (f, list_type(B1(a1)));
}

struct Convertible
{
   Convertible(int a) : b(a) {}
   int b;
};

int foo(Convertible bar)
{
   return 2+bar.b;
}

void mainFunc()
{
   int x = 3;
   b::function<int()> funcObj = mybind(foo, x);
   printf("val: %d\n", funcObj());
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are different cases where you *need* the arguments to be processed at the call site.

The first such example is calling a member function, where you can either have the member called on a copy of the object (`boost::bind( &std::vector<int>::push_back, myvector)`) which most probably you don't want, or else you need to pass a pointer and the binder will dereference the pointer as needed (`boost::bind( &std::vector<int>::push_back, &myvector )`) --Note both options can make sense in different programs

Another important use case is passing an argument *by reference* to a function. `bind` will *copy* performing the equivalent to a pass-by-value call. The library offers the option of wrapping arguments through the helper functions `ref` and `cref`, both of which store a pointer to the actual object to be passed, and at the place of call they dereference the pointer (through an implicit conversion). If the conversion to the target type was performed at bind time, then this would be impossible to implement.

Comment: I like the second paragraph here as an answer.  It definitely breaks ref/cref, which are definitely useful.  I'm a bit confused by the first paragraph.  Wouldn't std::vector<int>::push_back take a std::vector<int>* as the first (implicit) argument?  Under the hood I assume bind has to special case this anyway since it uses ->* not ->.  I think it may reuse memfn.

Comment: @Soverman: Same difference. Whether it internally calls `.*` on an object or `->*` on a pointer the fact is that it cannot be the same for all uses of bind. Consider `bind( &A::f, a )`, `bind( &A::f, &a )` and `bind( &A::f, _1 )`. In the first case it will copy the `a` object internally and then call `(first.*mbr)()`, in the second `(first->*mbr)()` and in the third case depending on what the argument at the place of call is (alternatively it could always use `.*` applied to either `first` or `*first` depending on whether the stored/passed in first argument (`first`) is a pointer or not...

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but I think the first paragraph boils down to the same "it doesn't work with function overloads" argument as the other answers, only with a rather special case of overloaded functions/functors (those supported by the objects returned by mem_fn).  Bind clearly is supposed to work for this particular case, so I think it's a valid argument.  However, it's a special-case anyway, so it could be handled as such (store based on the type of the argument, but only in this case).  That's why it seems like the `ref` / `cref` argument is stronger.

Comment: Actually, couldn't you just handle `ref`/`cref` with partial template specialization?

Answer (score 4):

Because the functor may support multiple overloads, which may give different behaviours. Even if this signature could be resolved when you knew all the arguments (and I don't know if Standard C++ can guarantee this facility) `bind` does not know all the arguments, and therefore it definitely cannot be provided. Therefore, `bind` does not possess the necessary information.

Edit: Just to clarify, consider

```
struct x {
    void operator()(int, std::vector<float>);
    void operator()(float, std::string);
};

int main() {
    auto b = std::bind(x(), 1); // convert or not?
}
```

Even if you were to reflect on the struct and gain the knowledge of it's overloads, it's still undecidable as to whether you need to convert the `1` to a float or not.

Comment: As far as I can tell it does have enough information, at least in the case of plain functions.  See my posted code snipped (based off the actual boost bind implementation).

Comment: Ah, I think I understand what you're saying now, I missed that you were referring to using bind on a functor.  I thought you were referring to the functor returned by bind.

Comment: Code does not use `boost::bind`? It does not compile with `boost::bind`?

Comment: @David: `std::bind` is functionally equivalent, except it can use `decltype` in this case and doesn't need the explicit template argument.

Comment: @DeadMG: The code above does not compile with `boost::bind`, I have not tested with `std::bind`, but either they are not equivalent or the example does not compile...

Comment: @David: "except it can use `decltype` and does not require the explicit argument". Try `boost::bind<void>`.

Answer (score 2):

I think this is due to the fact that bind has to work with any callable entity, be it a function pointer, `std::function<>`, or your own functor `struct` with `operator()`. This makes bind generic on any type that can be called using `()`. I.e. Bind's implicit requirement on your functor is just that it can be used with `()`

If bind was to store the function argument types, it would have to somehow infer them for any callable entity passed in as a type parameter. This would obviously not be as generic, since deducing parameter types of an `operator()` of a passed-in struct type is impossible without relying on the user to specify some kind of `typedef` (as an example). As a result the requirement on the functor (or *concept*) is no longer concrete/simple.

I am not entirely sure this is the reason, but it's one of the things that would be a problem.

EDIT: Another point as DeadMG mentions in another answer, overloads would create ambiguities even for standard function pointers, since the compiler would not be able to resolve the functor type. By storing the types you provide to bind and using `()`, this problem is also avoided.

Comment: This seems promising.  I've only ever used boost::bind on functions and member functions, never functors.  Do you have any references about the ambiguity of deducing parameter types for functors?  I need to think a bit more about it before I'm convinced one way or another.

Comment: OK, I think I'm convinced.  Bind could still require an explicit template argument, [as is the case with return values of functors](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_50_0/libs/bind/bind.html#with_function_objects), but that would definitely be a usability issue.

Comment: Actually, I'm no longer convinced.  Apparently boost::bind [is not intended to support overloads](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/libs/bind/bind.html#err_overloaded).

Comment: @Soverman: That's only for binding function, and member function, pointers, as the language requires disambiguation at pointer generation site.

Comment: I agree, although unless I'm missing something in the docs that's more implementation detail than intent.  I think that's where the "usually results in an error" part comes in.  This is the case where it does not.  Do you see anywhere in the docs that suggest binding in the presence of overloads is OK?

Answer (score 0):

A good example would binding "std::future"s to some ordinary function taking ordinary types:

Say I want to use an ordinary f(x,y) function in an incredibly asynchronous way. Namely, I want to call it like "f(X.get(), Y.get())". There's a good reason for this- I can just call that line and f's logic will run as soon as both inputs are available (I don't need separate lines of code for the join). To do this I need the following:

1) I need to support implicit conversions "std::future<T> -> T". This means std::future or my custom equivalent needs a cast operator:

```
operator T() { return get(); }
```

2) Next, I need to bind my generic function to hide all its parameters

```
// Hide the parameters
template<typename OUTPUT, typename... INPUTS>
std::function<OUTPUT()> BindVariadic(std::function<OUTPUT(INPUTS...)> f,
                                     INPUTS&&... in)
{
   std::function<OUTPUT()> stub = std::bind( f, std::forward<INPUTS>(in)...);
   return stub;
}
```

With a std::bind that does the "std::function<T> -> T" conversion at call time, I only wait for all the input parameters to become available when I ACTUALLY CALL "stub()". If it did the conversion via operator T() at the bind, the logic would silently force the wait when I actually constructed "stub" instead of when I use it. That might be fatal if "stub()" cannot always run safely in the same thread I built it.

There are other use cases that also forced that design choice. This elaborate one for async processing is simply the one I'm personally familiar with.